# Return type in TypeScript function with Generic Constraints has concrete values instead of types

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-constraints

```
function createGenericCoordinates<Type extends number | string>(
  x: Type,
  y: Type
) {
  return { x, y };
}

const genericCoordinates = createGenericCoordinates(1, 2);

// Error (TS2322)
// Type 3 is not assignable to type 1 | 2
genericCoordinates.x = 3;
```

How can I change this function so that the return type of both x and y is either number or string instead of the values I passed as x and y as argument functions (1|2 in this example)? If I remove „extends number | string“ it works, but the the allowed values for Type are not limited to number or string. Tested with TS 5.1.6

Comment: @jcalz Yes, thanks, that works! I just would love to understand why my code doesn't work, and especially why <Type extends number | string> changes the return type to concrete values and <Type> doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript uses various heuristic rules to determine whether a string or numeric literal like `"a"` or `2` should be given a [literal type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) like `"a"` or `2`, or a corresponding *widened* type like `string` or `number`.  These rules have been found to work well in a wide range of situations in real world code, but they don't always happen to agree with everyone's expectations.

Many of the rules in question were implemented in and described in [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676). In particular, "during type argument inference for a call expression the type inferred for a type parameter `T` is widened to its widened literal type if [...] `T` has no constraint or its constraint does not include primitive or literal types". So given the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function

```
function createGenericCoordinates<T extends number | string>(
    x: T, y: T
) { return { x, y }; }
```

the type parameter `T` has a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) which includes the primitive types `string` and `number`, so when the type argument for `T` is inferred, it will *not* be widened.

This suggests that one approach to change this is to remove the constraint from `T` and write the rest of your call signature so it enforces the intended constraint.  Maybe like this:

```
function createGenericCoordinates<T>(
    x: T & (string | number), y: T & (string | number)) {
    return { x, y };
}
```

Now `T` is unconstrained so `T` *will* be widened when inferred.  When you call `createGenericCoordinates(x, y)`, the compiler will infer `T` from the type of `x`, but then check that `x` is assignable to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `T & (string | number)`, and the same check will happen for `y`.  The only way that is possible is if `T extends string | number`, so if either `x` or `y` are not compatible with `string | number`, you'll get an error:

```
createGenericCoordinates(true, false); // error!
// --------------------> ~~~~
// function createGenericCoordinates<boolean>(x: never, y: never);

createGenericCoordinates({}, {}); // error!
// --------------------> ~~
// function createGenericCoordinates<{}>(x: string | number, y: string | number);
```

Since `boolean & (string | number)` reduces to `never`, the compiler rejects `true` because it's not `never`.  Since `{} & (string | number)` reduces to `string | number`, he compiler rejects `{}` because it's not `string | number`.

If you call it with two strings or two numbers, there's no error, and the lack of widening gives you the results you wanted:

```
createGenericCoordinates(1, 2);
// function createGenericCoordinates<number>(x: number, y: number);

createGenericCoordinates("a", "b");
// function createGenericCoordinates<string>(x: string, y: string);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6#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-tuoHQK87yfLgQA)